# Oracle stored procedure help

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

HI am new to stored procedure.
Am using a dynamic sql with

```
select * from table into var
```

var is a variable.the var contains more than one value ,when i try to run the proc with inputs i get an error:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Is there a way such that the variable can hold more than one row using dynamic sql.

Comment: Can we see your stored procedure?

Comment: Kudos to Quassnoi for identifying Oracle as teh database from just the text of ORA-01422 error message.

Answer (score 4):

Use collection variables:

```
DECLARE
        TYPE tt_int IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
        var tt_int;
BEGIN
        SELECT  id
        BULK COLLECT
        INTO    var
        FROM    table;
END;
```

Comment: This won't work on Oracle. You need to put the `bulk collect` imediatly after the select id, before the `from table`.

Comment: am using that var (as in above example) in the IN clause as name in (var).Am getting an error as inconsistent datatypes.How to solve it ??any idea ??

Comment: @prasanna: `WHERE name IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(var AS tt_int)))`. You will have to declare `tt_int` as a persistent type for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `bulk collect` the result set into a `table of` type if you're going to select multiple rows.

```
declare
    type record_type is table of <table_name>;
    var_records record_type;

begin

    select * 
    bulk collect into var_records
    from <table_name>;

end;
/
```

See also my answer to [PL SQL how to select all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734279/pl-sql-how-to-select-all-columns/4734461#4734461)

Answer (score 1):

you can also return the results to a [ref cursor](http://psoug.org/reference/ref_cursors.html)

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE 
  REFEXAMPLE SYS_REFCURSOR;
  VAR NUMBER ;
  col varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    OPEN REFEXAMPLE FOR --Here you open the cursor and fill it
    SELECT * 
      FROM (
        SELECT 1 VAR, 'a' COL FROM DUAL 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 VAR, 'b' COL FROM DUAL 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 VAR, 'c' COL FROM DUAL 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 VAR, 'd' COL FROM DUAL 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5 VAR, 'e' COL FROM DUAL 
      ) EXAMPLETABLE ;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var   ' || 'col');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------');
    LOOP
        FETCH REFEXAMPLE INTO VAR, col; --now loop through
        EXIT WHEN REFEXAMPLE%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var || '     ' || col || '  ');
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE REFEXAMPLE;


end ;
/


var   col
---------
1     a  
2     b  
3     c  
4     D  
5     e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable, which provides you with an in-memory table of your results. You declare a table variable similar to a standard variable:

```
declare @MyVar table (col1 col1type, col2 col2type, etc.)
```